# Calculating Azimuths for Lunar Major/Minor Standstill in PyEphem

Tags: astronomy, pyephem

Is it possible to use PyEphem to calculate:

1. Given a starting year, find the next year for both major/minor lunar
   standstills?
2. Use these dates to find the moonrise/moonset azimuths of a given X,Y location?

I can't seem to find information about standstills in the PyEphem documentation. If PyEphem can't do this, does anyone know of another piece or software or library that can help?